# single field won't insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason a single field will not insert into my database (email field). I cannot find anything wrong. I have echoed out the variable for it fine. However nothing seems to insert even manual text. Can anyone see an error?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users' (fbID, firstName, lastName, facebookURL, birthday, updated, accessToken, emailOne) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($userId)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($firstName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($lastName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($link)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($birthday)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($today)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($accessToken)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."')");
```

Comment: The field in the database is varchar for reference

Comment: what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: No errors. just does not insert anything

Comment: Considering it works fine when you query the db through phpmyadmin leads me to believe that $email does not contain what you think it contains at this point in the code (Yes, I know you echoed it but look again)

Otherwise, may I also recommend using the php [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: try it without using mysql_real_escape_string with email field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it up for debugging.

```
myQuery="INSERT INTO `users` (fbID, firstName, ... ";
mysql_query(myQuery);

echo myQuery;
```

So you can print out your query and paste this one into your phpmyadmin for testing.
You should get an error if something is not working.

Introduce some error handling like mentioned in the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query(myQuery);
  if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

If your query is correct it should work. Otherwise it should tell you about an error.

Answer (score 0):

Single-quotes are for string and date literals in SQL.  You may need back-quotes or no quotes.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (...
```

It's really difficult to debug SQL by looking at PHP code that generates SQL.  You should learn how to form an SQL string and output that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (...)";

// you can output the string here to debug it

mysql_query($sql);
```

Often by looking at the SQL string, not the PHP code, any errors are much more clear.

You should also check for error conditions after any query.  mysql_query() returnse FALSE if anything goes wrong, and you can check what happened by using mysql_error().  See code examples at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: removed them. all fields enter but that email field still